# Priority Queue Objective-C++?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, priority-queue

I'm working on a path finding algorithm and want to implement a priority queue to speed it up.

I'm adding my `Node` Object to the queue based on the property `fScore`. With the smallest `fScore` always added to the top of the queue.

What are my options for this? Would it best to implement a c++ priority queue using stl? If so how would I set this up to take in my objective-c object `Node` and how would I specify what the list is being ordered on (`Node.fScore`).

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if boost works with Objective-C++ (I never worked with Objective-C++) but they have [a good priority queue aka heap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/heap.html). I guess `std::priority_queue` will not satisfy your needs as it doesn't provide priority changing functionality, which boost heap does.

Comment: @leemes I'm 99% certain that boost works with Objective-C++, in fact any C++ library should work with Objective-C++. So unless OP specifically wants to implement his/her own solution I would consider this to be the best answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `std:: priority_queue`, if you are using ARC you should be 90% of the way there. STL container will automatically store strong references. WIN!

You will need to create a custom compare class.

```
typedef std::priority_queue<MyClass *, std::vector<MyClass *>, MyClassCompare> MyPriorityQueue;
```

I'm not exactly sure how you will want to implement your compare class. It will look something like:

```
class MyClassCompare {
    bool operator()(MyClass *lhs, MyClass *rhs) const {
        // magic!!! Be sure to return a bool.
    }
};
```

---

### Example Wrapper Class

MyClassQueue.h

```
@interface MyClassQueue : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) MyClass *topObject;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger count;
- (void)pushObject:(MyClass *)myObject;
- (void)popObject;
- (void)popAllObjects;
@end
```

MyClassQueue.mm

```
#import "MyClassQueue.h"
#include <queue>
#import "MyClass.h"

class MyClassCompare {
    bool operator()(MyClass *lhs, MyClass *rhs) const {
        // magic!!! Be sure to return a bool.
    }
};

typedef std::priority_queue<MyClass *, std::vector<MyClass *>, MyClassCompare> MyPriorityQueue;

@interface MyClassQueue ()
@property (nonatomic) MyPriorityQueue *queue;
@end
@implementation MyClassQueue

- (MyClass *)topObject {
    return !self.queue->empty() ? self.queue->top() : nil;
}

- (NSUInteger)count {
    return (NSUInteger)self.queue->size();
}

- (void)pushObject:(MyClass *)myObject {
    self.queue->push(myObject);
}

- (void)popObject {
    if (!self.queue->empty()) {
        self.queue->pop();
    }
}

- (void)popAllObjects {
    if (!self.queue->empty()) {
        delete _queue;
        _queue = new MyPriorityQueue();
    }
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _queue = new MyPriorityQueue();
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    delete _queue;
    _queue = NULL;
}    
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have implemented that class to check the size of my values like so: return lhs.fScore > rhs.fScore; My only question is where do I define that typedef, I've tried changing my .m file to .mm, and adding it to various places in the header but it still won't compile. Sorry if its a basic question but I've never done this before and all of the examples are for different llvm compilers

Comment: I've added #import "queue" but it still can't find my custom class, does it have to be defined anywhere in particular?

Comment: I'm not sure about `#import "queue"`. I would use `#include <queue>`. As far as the typedef and the compare class, it's really up to you how you want to organize things. I would wrap them in an Objective C class to limit the number of .mm files you need.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm guessing the file needs to be set as objective-c++?